# Cannot get original executable path for .NET Core 3.0 single file '/p:PublishSingleFile=true'

Tags: c#, .net-core

I published a .NET Core console app with '/p:PublishSingleFile=true' option, but now assembly path is the temporary path where it inflated to.

`Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

now returns:

`C:\Users\DEFUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\myApp\3dzfa4fp.353\_myApp.json`

originally:

`C:\devel\myApp\bin\publish\_myApp.json`

How can I get the original path of where i put the exe file originally?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/25623, which was also [confirmed by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoIFindWhichDirectoryMyNETCoreConsoleApplicationWasStartedInOrIsRunningFrom.aspx) a year later:

- .NET Core: `Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)`
- .NET 5: `AppContext.BaseDirectory`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new .NET 6.0 property [`Environment.ProcessPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processpath?view=net-6.0) added exactly for that reason

> Returns the path of the executable that started the currently
> executing process

Design notes can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40862)

Answer (score 1):

Docs for single-file deployment and executable mention that [some `Assembly` APIs will not work in this mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#api-incompatibility), including `Location`, which will return an empty string:

| API | Note |
| --- | --- |
| `Assembly.CodeBase` | Throws `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`. |
| `Assembly.EscapedCodeBase` | Throws `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`. |
| `Assembly.GetFile` | Throws `System.IO.IOException`. |
| `Assembly.GetFiles` | Throws `System.IO.IOException`. |
| `Assembly.Location` | Returns an empty string. |
| `AssemblyName.CodeBase` | Returns `null`. |
| `AssemblyName.EscapedCodeBase` | Returns `null`. |
| `Module.FullyQualifiedName` | Returns a string with the value of `<Unknown>` or throws an exception. |
| `Marshal.GetHINSTANCE` | Returns -1. |
| `Module.Name` | Returns a string with the value of `<Unknown>`. |

There are some workarounds mentioned:

- To access files next to the executable, use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`
- To find the file name of the executable, use the first element of `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, or starting with .NET 6, use the file name from `System.Environment.ProcessPath`.

So based on this you can use `Environment.ProcessPath` (since .NET 6) or `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` (since .NET 5, can be preferable in cases when the executable is distributed and run in different ways, i.e. via single file, .exe or via `dotnet` command).

From [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=net-7.0):

> The first element in the array contains the file name of the executing program. If the file name is not available, the first element is equal to String.Empty. The remaining elements contain any additional tokens entered on the command line.
>
> In .NET 5 and later versions, for single-file publishing, the first element is the name of the host executable.